# UserProperties vs. userProperties - How can I maintain persistency between scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

The old UserProperties maintained persistency between scripts for a user - "User Properties are key-value pairs unique to a user. User Properties are scoped per user; any script running under the identity of a user can access User Properties for that user only." (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/user-properties)

However the new properties services userProperties behave differently - it is relevant only for "The current user of the current script" (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#comparison_of_property_stores).

I need to save data between scripts. Anyone has any idea how this can be done without saving data in an external spreadsheet or document to be retrieved by scripts?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a lot of mileage using scripts as libraries of each other. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries#writingLibrary) gives a good guide about how the scoping of variables and properties [just below](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries#scoping).

Essentially you can pass in or out of a Library's script objects that reside in its own scope.

Script 1:

```
//set a dummy data object

PropertiesService
  .getUserProperties()
  .setProperty('data', 'i come from script 1');

function script1Properties() {  
  var up = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  return up;
}
```

Script 2:

```
//set a dummy data object in this script too.

PropertiesService
  .getUserProperties()
  .setProperty('data', 'i come from script 2');

function script2() {

  var up1 = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var up2 = Script1.publishProperties();

  Logger.log(up1.getProperty('data'));
  Logger.log(up2.getProperty('data'));

  debugger
}
```

Attach Script 1 to Script 2 as a Library. 
[image: Library attachment Screen]

`> Run Script`

Output in the Console:

```
[15-01-08 15:55:41:493 GMT] i come from script 1
[15-01-08 15:55:41:501 GMT] i come from script 2
```

Comment: Jonathon. Thanks for that. However, this will still limit the property to a specific script. Each user may have hundreds of properties and I may have 10,000 users or more... Is there away to keep the properties at a user level (not script!)? Thanks.

Comment: Well, they are user properties tied to a script which can be any script under your or another users cintrol. Admittedly though you wont do this for 10000 users. And hundreds of scripts. Ill think, but i suspect you'll be doing sonething different like maintaining user settings by account key in a database running under one script and callung that as described above.

Comment: Yes. I can do it through a database but at the moment I am using the old implementation of UserProperties which worked fine as it only maintained the properties per user and not per script. Are you saying that my only solution now is to keep these properties in a database and have different script either accessing the database or having one script which will be called by the other accessing it? Thx!

Comment: That's my understanding, yes. It's a sensible security change in the wider context. In specific use cases that relied on the old way (I had plenty managing google apps domains) it was a pain to do it the new way. On the other hand storing properties per user yourself stops malicious or errant activity from the user direction who previously had total control of what they provided independent of your script.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. It started by having a few user properties and grew over time to nearly 200. It was a very effective (albeit unsecured) way to share information between script in regard to a user without the need for a database... It now requires a major modifications all across :-(